# How do I delete a specific node in a linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, linked-list, structure

I am facing a problem where I cannot seem to be able to locate a specific node and then delete that node from the linked list. I have tried to create while loop shown at the very end, to loop the memory allocation of head two times which contains the nodes and then delete it but it seems to delete both nodes if I set `deleteNode` to 2.

```cpp
void delete_list(Book *&head, Book *&last){
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Database is already empty! \n";
    }
    else if (head == last){
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        last = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter the number of the node you would like to delete \n";
        cin >> deleteNode;

        Book* new_book = head;

        while(deleteNode>0) {
            head = head -> next;
            deleteNode--;
        }
        delete new_book;
    }
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



struct Book{

    string title;
    string author;
    string publisher;
    int publishYear;
    int isbn;
    Book* next;
};

void add_node(Book*&, Book*&);
void print_list(Book*);
void delete_list(Book*& , Book*& );
int deleteNode;


int main()
{

    Book* head = NULL;
    Book* last = NULL;

  char option;
    do{

        cout << "Press required option: \n" "To Add Book detail   [A]\n"
                "To Print Book details   [P]\n" "To Delete Book details   [D]\n"
                "Quit  [Q]\n";
                cin >> option;

      switch(option){
          case 'A':
          add_node(head, last);
          break;

          case 'P':
          print_list(head);
          break;

          case 'D':
          delete_list(head, last);

          case 'Q':
          break;

          default:
          cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;

      }
    } while (option != 'Q');

    return 0;
}


void add_node(Book *&head, Book *&last){
    //Cheaks the empty link list
    if (head == NULL){

    Book* new_book = new Book();

    cout <<"Enter Book name \n";
    cin >> new_book -> title;

    cout << "Enter author name \n";
    cin >> new_book -> author;


    cout << "Enter publisher name \n";
    cin >> new_book -> publisher;

    cout << "Enter publish year \n";
    cin >> new_book -> publishYear;

    cout << "Enter ISBN number \n";
    cin >> new_book -> isbn;


    new_book -> next = NULL;
    head = new_book;
    last = new_book;

    }

    else
    {
        Book* new_book1 = new Book;

    cout <<"Enter Book name \n";
    cin >> new_book1 -> title;

    cout << "Enter author name \n";
    cin >> new_book1 -> author;


    cout << "Enter publisher name \n";
    cin >> new_book1 -> publisher;

    cout << "Enter publish year \n";
    cin >> new_book1 -> publishYear;

    cout << "Enter ISBN number \n";
    cin >> new_book1 -> isbn;


        last -> next = new_book1;
        last =  new_book1;
    }

}


void print_list(Book* in_root){

    Book* next_ptr;
    next_ptr = in_root;
    if(next_ptr == NULL)
    {
        cout << "No information found! \n";

    }

    else
    {
        while (next_ptr != NULL){
            cout << "Book Name: "<<next_ptr -> title << endl;
            cout << "Author Name: "<<next_ptr -> author << endl;
            cout << "Publisher: "<<next_ptr -> publisher << endl;
            cout << "Publishing Year: "<<next_ptr -> publishYear << endl;
            cout << "ISBN Number: "<<next_ptr -> isbn << endl;
            cout << " \n";
            next_ptr = next_ptr -> next;
        }
    }
}


void delete_list(Book *&head, Book *&last){


    if (head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Database is already empty! \n";
    }

    else if (head == last){
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        last = NULL;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter the number of the node you would like to delete \n";
        cin >> deleteNode;

        Book* new_book = head;

      while(deleteNode>0){

        head = head -> next;
        deleteNode--;
      }
      delete new_book;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with fully working example so we can test it easily.

Comment: I like that the function params are reference pointers

Comment: @NutCracker I have provided the full code. It's supposed to be a program that stores book information in dynamic memory in nodes and the user can delete a specific book with all its information

Comment: Deleting *any* node in a single-linked list involves one thing: Find the pointer that refers to that node and  prune the node from the list. That pointer can be (a) the `head` pointer, or (b) some `next` pointer in some other node.  There are no other options. And fyi, this is easier (imho) when using a pointer-to-pointer to walk the actual list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not updating the nodes that *surround* the node being deleted. You are not updating the `head` or `last` pointers when deleting a node from the front or back of the list.  And you are updating the caller's `head` pointer while simply iterating the list, effectively corrupting the caller's list.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void delete_list(Book* &head, Book* &last)
{
    if (!head)
    {
        cout << "Database is already empty! \n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter the number of the node you would like to delete \n";
        int deleteNode = -1;
        cin >> deleteNode;

        if (deleteNode < 1)
        {
            cout << "Invalid node number \n";
            return;
        }

        Book* book = head, *previous = NULL;

        while ((book) && (--deleteNode > 0))
        {
            previous = book;
            book = book->next;
        }

        if (!book)
        {
            cout << "Invalid node number \n";
            return;
        }

        if (previous)
            previous->next = book->next;

        if (head == book)
            head = book->next;

        if (last == book)
            last = previous;

        delete book;
    }
}
```

That said, there are some other issues with your code.  Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

struct Book
{
    string title;
    string author;
    string publisher;
    int publishYear;
    int isbn;

    Book* next;
};

void add_node(Book*&, Book*&);
void print_list(Book*);
void delete_list(Book*&, Book*&);

int main()
{
    Book* head = NULL;
    Book* last = NULL;

    char option;

    do
    {
        cout << "Press required option: \n"
                "To Add Book detail   [A]\n"
                "To Print Book details   [P]\n"
                "To Delete Book details   [D]\n"
                "Quit  [Q]\n";

        if (!(cin >> option))
        {
            option = '\0';
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        }

        switch (option)
        {
            case 'A':
                add_node(head, last);
                break;

            case 'P':
                print_list(head);
                break;

            case 'D':
                delete_list(head, last);
                break;

            case 'Q':
                break;

            default:
                cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                break;
        }
    }
    while (option != 'Q');

    return 0;
}

void add_node(Book *&head, Book *&last)
{
    Book* new_book = new Book;

    cout << "Enter Book name \n";
    getline(cin, new_book->title);

    cout << "Enter author name \n";
    getline(cin, new_book->author);

    cout << "Enter publisher name \n";
    getline(cin, new_book->publisher);

    cout << "Enter publish year \n";
    cin >> new_book->publishYear;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "Enter ISBN number \n";
    cin >> new_book->isbn;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    new_book->next = NULL;

    //Checks the empty link list
    if (!head) {
        head = last = new_book;
    }
    else
    {
        last->next = new_book;
        last = new_book;
    }
}

void print_list(Book* root)
{
    if (!root)
    {
        cout << "No information found! \n";
        return;
    }

    Book* book = root;
    do
    {
        cout << "Book Name: " << book->title << endl;
        cout << "Author Name: " << book->author << endl;
        cout << "Publisher: " << book->publisher << endl;
        cout << "Publishing Year: " << book->publishYear << endl;
        cout << "ISBN Number: " << book->isbn << endl;
        cout << " \n";
        book = book->next;
    }
    while (book);
}

void delete_list(Book* &head, Book* &last)
{
    if (!head)
    {
        cout << "Database is already empty! \n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter the number of the node you would like to delete \n";

        int deleteNode;
        if (!(cin >> deleteNode))
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
            return;
        }

        if (deleteNode < 1)
        {
            cout << "Invalid node number \n";
            return;
        }

        Book* book = head, *previous = NULL;

        while ((book) && (--deleteNode > 0))
        {
            previous = book;
            book = book->next;
        }

        if (!book)
        {
            cout << "Invalid node number \n";
            return;
        }

        if (previous)
            previous->next = book->next;

        if (head == book)
            head = book->next;

        if (last == book)
            last = previous;

        delete book;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You have a couple issues here. First, when you do `head = head->next` to go through your list, you are actively reassigning the head pointer and therefore loosing nodes from your list. You should make a temporary node, conventionally called `curr` for current. Then set `curr = head` and in the while loop do `curr = curr->next`

The other problem is that you delete a node in the middle of the list which effectively cuts your list into two pieces but don't put the two pieces back together. You'll need to make another temporary variable to point to the node you want to delete, `Book* deleteMe = curr->next`. Set `curr->next = curr->next->next` then `delete deleteMe`